# Is there a way to merge three dicts from three separate for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am using Pandas to create three lists based on the data from three separate columns of my CSV file. My lists are:

```
order_list = df['order'][:10].tolist()) 
user_id_list = df['user_id'][:10].tolist())
company_id_list = df['company_id'][:10].tolist())
```

Inside my `create_order()` function, I am looping through each list and using `enumerate()` to add the items to three seperate dicts. For example:

```
def create_order(orders, users, companies):

    for index, order in enumerate(orders):
        x = {
            'name': order,
        }
    for index, user_id in enumerate(users):
        y = {
            'user': user_id,
        }
    for index, company_id in enumerate(companies):
        z = {
            'company': company_id,
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_order(order_list, user_id_list, company_id_list)
```

I want to merge all three dicts together and return the data for each row of data from my CSV file. However, I need the `order` objects to be unique. I have been able to merge the dicts returned using [unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). e.g. `{**x, **y}`. The only way I can accomplish merging the dicts this way if I make nested for-loops; which prevents me from returning unique orders.

What would the best approach be to merge my dictionary into one dict so I can loop through and return unique data with unique orders?

### EDIT w/ Corrections

Here is my original DF output:

```
     company_id                 user_id          order
  0         111                     222           order 1
  1         111                     222           order 1
  2         111                     222           order 1
  3         111                     222           order 2
  4         111                     222           order 2
  5         111                     222           order 3
```

Below is an example of my desired output with all unique orders:

```
company_id   user_id               order
       111       222             order 1
       111       222             order 2
       111       222             order 3
```

The reason for trying to solve the problem with for loops was the need to have all of the desired output to return a dict to import to a database via Google DFP API.

Below is the working code with the desired output thanks to the guidance from @MeHdi.

```
df = pd.read_csv('order_data.csv')

order_list = df['order'].tolist()
user_id_list = df['user_id'].tolist()
company_id_list = df['company_id']].tolist()

for x in company_id_list:
    company_id = int(x)

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'name': order_list,
            'userId': user_id_list,
            'companyId': company_id
        }
    )

 list_obj = df.reindex(columns=['companyId', 'userId', 'name']).drop_duplicates()

 records = list_obj.to_dict('records')
 print(records)
```

This returns the desired output as listed above.

Comment: What does your input look like, with respect to the output shown?

Comment: You probably do not need to separate in three lists and do three different for loops. Post the original `df`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work on your original DataFrame. Use reindex and drop_duplicates functions on your DataFrame to achieve required result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order':['order1', 'order2', 'order3', 'order3'], 'user_id':[222, 222, 222, 222], 'company_id':[111, 111, 111, 111], 'column_d':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

print(df)

df.reindex(columns=['company_id', 'user_id', 'order']).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried drop_duplicates method earlier without success. Was not aware of reindex- that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great. Absolutely, reindex first drops the columns you don't need (or takes the columns you need) and then applying drop_duplicates on the new selected columns gives you the result you want. Good Luck.